# Find angle with trigonometry

Tags: trigonometry

I try to find an expression for $\gamma$ in the following sketch:

[image]

The capital letters $A$, $B$ $D$ and $L$ indicate given values, the small letters $d$, $i_1$, $i_2$ and $k$ are used for intermediate variables, but should be able to be computed with only the given values. The same holds true for the angles $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

The goal is now to find an expression for $\gamma$ in terms of $A$, $B$, $D$ and $L$.

My ideas:
\begin{equation}
k = i_1 + i_2 + D
\end{equation}
Using equations for the parallelogram i find

\begin{equation}
D = d \sin \left( \frac{\pi}{2} - \gamma \right)
\end{equation}

and

\begin{equation}
L = k \sin \left( \frac{\pi}{2} + \gamma \right)
\end{equation}

Based on similar triangles

\begin{equation}
\frac{i_1}{B} = \frac{i_2}{A}
\end{equation}

If I could find an expression for either $i_1$ or $i_2$ in terms of $A$, $B$, $D$ and $L$ I could plug it into the equations and solve for $\gamma$, but I am stuck at the moment.
I also tried to solve for $\alpha$ and $\beta$, and work my way from there to $\gamma$, but I end up with $\gamma$ in the expression for $\beta$

(see EDIT)

EDIT based on comments (find $\alpha$):

By using two triangles:

\begin{equation}
\tan(\alpha) = \frac{l_4}{A/2}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\tan(\alpha) = \frac{l_3}{B/2}
\end{equation}

where $l_3$ and $l_4$ are intermediate values such that $l_3 + l_4 = D$. By rearranging and adding the equations

\begin{equation}
\alpha = \tan^{-1} \left( \frac{2 D}{A+B} \right)
\end{equation}

Comment: So you ended up with $\beta=f(\gamma)$, then $\gamma=f^{-1}(\beta)$

Comment: @Divide1918 But both should be computable with only the given values of A, B, D and L. I can construct it with only knowing them.

Comment: Were you able to write any intermediate values in terms of the given values?

Comment: @Divide1918 Not really, I am stuck at finding an expression for either $i_1$ or $i_2$ in terms of only the given values. If that is possible I can work my way back and find all intermediate values.

Comment: Is this problem motivated by physics, specifically optics?

Comment: Also notice D/L=d/k

Comment: @Divide1918 The problem arose from a construction I would like to analyze, so more related to statics. D/L = d/k is already contained in the expressions for D and L, since sin(pi/2-x)/sin(pi/2+x) is always 1, so I don't see how this would be used to further solve the problem.

Comment: I presume that $\alpha\ne\beta$?

Comment: @Divide1918 yes, $\alpha \neq \beta$, only if $A = B$, then $\alpha = \beta$ and $\gamma = 0$

Comment: How did you find $\alpha$?

Comment: @Divide1918 Sorry, there was a mistake in the formula for $\alpha$, I edited the original question to include the new formula and how I came there.

Comment: $l_3\gt l_4$ or the other way?

Comment: @Divide1918 $l_4 \geq l_3$, if $A=B$ then $l_4=l_3$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109886/discussion-between-divide1918-and-georgebaker).